# Node streams: How can a readable stream emit another readable event if it has been drained (end was emitted)

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, stream

The node documentation says (of the `readable` event for a readable stream):

> Once the internal buffer is drained, a readable event will fire again when more data is available.

However, it also says:

> Event: 'end'
>
> This event fires when there will be no more data to read.
>
> Note that the end event will not fire unless the data is completely
>   consumed. This can be done by switching into flowing mode, or by
>   calling read() repeatedly until you get to the end.

So my question is, if a buffer is drained, won't it emit the `end` event which would prevent the `readable` event from being fired again?

Comment: I suppose it could be more clearly worded as "This event fires when there will never be any more data to read." So just because you've emptied the queue of things currently available to read, doesn't mean there won't be more data coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `end` does not occur when the buffer is drained.  `end` only occurs when the underlying resource declares it will not be pushing any more data.